# Getting text from AvalonEdit with UIAutomation

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, avalonedit

I'm doing some work with UIAutomation and need to get the content of an AvalonEdit control in WPF. I am only able to get hold of the AvalonEdit control as a ControlType of Text:

```
var editors = app.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Text));
```

This is not supported...

```
var targetTextPattern = editor[0].GetCurrentPattern( TextPattern.Pattern) as TextPattern;
```

I can't seem to find a way to extract the text content from this, is it not possible to do when using ControlType.Text? I have also tried using ControlType Edit & Document but AvalonEdit doesn't seem to support them.

Any help is appretiated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging in the source code I found that AvalonEdit.TextEditor does support UIAutomation. These are the complete steps necessary to use it.

First, use ControlType.Custom to find the TextEditor:

```
allEditors = app.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));
```

TextEditorAutomationPeer class implements IValueProvider, so to get the text from TextEditor using UIAutomation, use ValuePattern like this:

```
var editorValuePattern = allEditors[0].GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
var text = editorValuePattern.Current.Value;
```

This worked for me :)